# What does Mgst mean?

Tags: legal-terms

I am reading about special education law.  In [this article](http://ahc.mo.gov/pdf/2016_IDEA_Administrative_Law_Judge_Training.pdf), I see phrases like this:

> Court adopted Mgst recommendation and ruled that ...

What does "Mgst" mean?

Answer (score 5):

In context I suspect it means [**magistrate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magistrate#United_States).

Comment: A magistrate is sort of a deputy judge, usually hired by the regular judges and serving at will, whose has limited authority and can have his decisions second guessed by the regular judge (unless the parties consent to give the magistrate full authority to decide all matters in the case as if the magistrate were a regular judge). In federal court, their official title is "magistrate judge".